# Optimizing MySQL/PHP queries

Tags: php, mysql

My database looks something like this:

```
[foods]
foods_id, foods_name, groups_id, producers_id

[producers]
producers_id, producers_name

[groups]
groups_id, groups_name
```

PHP:

```php
<?php
$producers = mysql_query('SELECT p.producers_name,p.producers_id FROM foods as f,producers as p WHERE p.producers_id = f.producers_id AND f.groups_id = 1 GROUP BY p.producers_name');
    //list the producer...
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($producers, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $foods = mysql_query('SELECT foods_id, foods_name FROM foods WHERE producers_id = '.$row['producers_id'].' ORDER BY foods_name ASC');       
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($foods, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            //list the foods under this producer...
        }
    }
?>
```

GOAL:

```
PRODUCER A
   FOOD A
   FOOD B
   FOOD C
PRODUCER B
   FOOD D
   FOOD E
PRODUCER C
   FOOD F
...
```

SOLUTION:

```
<?php
$res = mysql_query('SELECT f.foods_id, f.foods_name, p.producers_id, p.producers_name FROM foods f, producers p WHERE p.producers_id = f.producers_id AND f.groups_id = '.$_GET['g'].' ORDER BY p.producers_name ASC, f.foods_name ASC');       
$xproducers = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res , MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    if(!array_key_exists($row['producers_id'],$xproducers)){
        $xproducers[$row['producers_id']] = array('id'=>$row['producers_id'],'name'=>$row['producers_name'],'foods'=>array());
    }
    array_push($xproducers[$row['producers_id']]['foods'],array('id'=>$row['foods_id'],'name'=>$row['foods_name']));
}
?>
```

This solution is fast enough for me, maybe its not perfect but it does the job fine :) I thank you all for your awesome help!

Cheers

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: have you tried a JOIN? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant understand why you do first select, this get the same data.

```
$res = mysql_query('SELECT f.foods_id, f.foods_name, p.producers_id, p.producers_name FROM foods f, producers p WHERE p.producers_id = f.producers_id AND f.groups_id = 1');       
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res , MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $producers[$row['producers_id']][$row['foods_id']] = $row;
    }
```

Comment: Your right, i could use this in a PHP array and then work my way with this array, instead of querying the server xxx times. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would just do

```
mysql_query('SELECT producers_name, producers_id
FROM producers
WHERE producers_id IN
(SELECT producers_id FROM foods WHERE groups_id = 1)');
```

That should work much faster.

Best of luck!

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: This took way longer to just list the producers? Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 289 total, Query took 4.3762 sec)

Comment: I did fix that :P still took to long